# cognito credentials with college email only

Tags: android, validation, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to set the only way to login to a profile on an the app is for the user to login with a working email address from my college. I want to use AWS services and possibly simpleDB as the database. I am completely new to Android development and web services in general. If there is a tutorial out there for Cognito and setting up custom client credentials (may be wrong terminology, sorry if it is) please send me a link. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. Cognito supports developer authenticated identities. You probably need to build a backend to support it. You may find these links useful

- [Developer authenticated identities Part 1](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities)
- [Developer authenticated identities Part 2](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2FL1QAPDE0UAH/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-2-Developer-Authenticated-Ident)
- [Sample backend on Github](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-cognito-developer-authentication-sample)